# Third-Level Menu Items Are Always Showing

Tags: css

I am making a horizontal menu that is three levels deep. It works as intended for the first and second levels. However, when you hover over any of the first or second level menus, the third menu items are displayed.

Even more so, all third level menu items that are within the first level menu are displayed (all of the second level submenus). I have no idea how to correct this (I do, but I can't figure out the combination of ul li...etc).

*I realize my CSS and html is sloppy (black ftw) - that is going to get fixed later. My main concern now is to get it working correctly.

```
#menu ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position:relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px; /* Width of Menu Items */ 
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-width:2.3px;
    border-color:black;
    padding-left:0px;
    /*background:url(./images/fillers/vvv.png);*/
} 

#menu ul li { 
    /* position: relative; */
} 

#menu li ul { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 149px; /*Set 1px less than menu width */ 
    top: 0; 
    display: block; 
} 

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
} 

#menu li:hover ul { 
    visibility:visible; 
} 


#menu ul ul {
    visibility:hidden; 
} 


/* Fix IE. Hide from IE Mac \*/ 
* html #menu ul li { float: left; height: 1%; } 
* html #menu ul li a { height: 1%; } 
/* End */ 

/* Make-up syles */ 

#menu ul, li { 
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
} 

/* Styles for Menu Items */ 
#menu ul a { 
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;  
    padding: 4px; 
    border: 2.3px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 0;
} 

/* Hover Styles */ 
#menu ul li:hover, #menu ul li a:focus { 
    background-color:#5a5a5a;
    color:white;
    background:url(./images/fillers/vvv.png);
} 

/* Sub Menu Styles */ 
#menu li ul a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white; 
    text-align:center;
    padding: 4px; 
    border: 2.3px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 0;
} 

/* Sub Menu Hover Styles */ 
#menu li ul a:hover { 
    color: white;   
} 

#menu li ul a.noLink:hover, #menu li ul a.noLink, #menu .noLink, #menu li ul .noLink, #menu li a.noLink { 
    color: grey;    
} 
/* Icon Styles */ 
#menu ul a.submenu {background: url("r_arrow.gif") no-repeat right; } 
#menu ul a.submenu:hover {background: url("r_arrow.gif") no-repeat right;}




<div id=menu>
                                        <ul id=menuList>
                                            <li>
                                            <a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Tournaments</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">2011</a>

                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#"> 1, 2, 3</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#"> 4, 5, 6</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#"> 7, 8, 9</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#"> 10</a></li>
                                                            </ul>

                                                    </li> 

                                                    <li>
                                                    <a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">2012</a>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Season 1</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2013</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2014</a></li> 


                                                </ul>
                                            </li> 
                                            <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">---</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">2011</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">1, 2,  3</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                    </li> 
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2012</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2013</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2014</a></li> 
                                                </ul>
                                            </li> 
                                            <li><a class="noLink" name="submenu" class="submenu">Leagues</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2011</a></li> 
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2012</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2013</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2014</a></li> 
                                                </ul>
                                            </li> 
                                            <li><a class="noLink" name="submenu" class="submenu">---</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <a class="noLink" name="submenu" class="submenu">2011</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a class="noLink">---</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                    </li> 
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2012</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2013</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="noLink">2014</a></li> 
                                                </ul>
                                            </li> 

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: It's not that the third level `ul` isn't hidden, but a :hover state that also targets that `ul` and is making it visible again. You might want to make classes for your inner `ul`'s so you can target each individual `ul` on hover.

Comment: Here is a js fiddle of what he is trying to do, will try to have a look at it myself http://jsfiddle.net/muss/sJGzA/

Comment: I looked up classes, but am still confused by what was suggested. What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: The solution:

`#menu li:hover ul ul, #menu li:hover ul ul ul, #menu li:hover ul ul ul ul{
display:none;
}
#menu li:hover ul, #menu li li:hover ul, #menu li li li:hover ul, #menu li li li li:hover ul{
display:block;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this solution out:

```
#menu li:hover ul ul, #menu li:hover ul ul ul, #menu li:hover ul ul ul ul{
display:none;
}

#menu li:hover ul, #menu li li:hover ul, #menu li li li:hover ul, #menu li li li li:hover     ul{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - found the solution here and it worked for me

[CSS Drop Down Navigation, 3rd level issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752944/css-drop-down-navigation-3rd-level-issue)

You need to add an ">" between li:hover and ul

ie: li:hover > ul