# CSS Drop Down Navigation, 3rd level issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a 3rd level of flyout/dropdown on this CSS navigation menu. The second level works great, only shows when you're hovering over the right top level link. However, the 3rd level shows when you hover over the TOP level also. It should be hidden until you hover over the right dropdown link and then flyout to the right. I have the position correct, but I need it to hide until the right link is hovered on.

Here's the site I'm working on: http://174.37.160.21 (the 3rd tier is under Products).

Here's my CSS for the whole menu. I'm sure it's something really easy to spot but I've tried all that I can think of. I'm not a CSS wizard or anything.

```
.menu { height:32px; position:relative; z-index:100; }
.menu ul {padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;}
.menu li {float:left;width:auto; padding-left:6px; padding-right:6px; position:relative;}
.menu ul li a { font-size:13px; }

.menu ul li ul li a { font-size:13px; }
.menu a, .menu a:visited {display:block; font-size:15px; text-decoration:none; color:#454545; height:30px; border:1px; padding-left:10px;}
.menu ul ul { visibility:hidden; position:absolute; height:0; top:20px; left:0; width:150px; }
.menu ul ul li { background:#272727; width:150px; text-align:left; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; }
.menu ul ul li:hover { background:#454545; }

.menu ul ul ul { visibility:hidden; position:absolute; height:0; top:0; left:150px; width:150px; }
.menu ul ul ul li { background:#272727; width:150px; text-align:left; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; }
.menu ul ul ul li:hover { background:#454545; }

.menu table {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border-collapse:collapse;} /* style the table so that it takes no ppart in the layout - required for IE to work */
.menu ul ul a, .menu ul ul a:visited, .menu ul ul ul a, .menu ul ul ul a:visited { color:#fff; height:auto;}
.menu a:hover, .menu ul ul li:hover { }
.menu :hover > a, .menu ul ul :hover > a, .menu ul ul ul :hover > a {}
.menu ul li:hover ul, .menu ul a:hover ul, .menu ul ul li:hover ul { visibility:visible; }
```

Here's is my HTML Code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a>
              <li><a href="/about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/garage-door-services.html">Services</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="/residential-garage-door-services.html">Residential</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/commercial-overhead-door-services.html">Commerical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/emergency-door-repair-services.html">Emergency</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/garage-door-preventative-maintenance.html">Maintenance</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
  <li><a href="/garage-door-products.html">Products</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Garage Doors</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Residential Garage Doors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Commercial Garage Doors</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Openers & Operators</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Online Store</a>
                     <ul>
                       <li><a href="/replacement-garage-door-remotes.html">Replacement Remotes</a></li>
                       <li><a href="/keyless-garage-entry.html">Keyless Entry</a></li>
                       <li><a href="/garage-door-gears-sprockets-parts.html">Gears & Sprocket Parts</a></li>
                         <li><a href="/garage-door-safety-beams.html">Safety Beams</a></li>
                         <li><a href="/garage-door-lube-grease.html">Lube & Grease</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Ask a Pro</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Submit a Question</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seasonal Tips</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part that makes the submenu visible:

```
.menu ul li:hover ul,
.menu ul a:hover ul,
.menu ul ul li:hover ul { visibility:visible; }
```

Now, I'm not sure what your markup is (I can only guess seeing `.menu table` and `a:hover ul`...), but with a standard list based markup, this part is too greedy:

```
.menu ul li:hover ul
```

This selects *all* `ul` elements that are in the `li:hover` all the way down the line, up to the very last one. I think you want to select only the direct descendant:

```
.menu ul li:hover > ul
```

All I changed was adding the `>` character. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dgUFw/

**EDIT**: Updated demo with the HTML you just posted: http://jsfiddle.net/dgUFw/1/

The `.menu` element was missing from your post, so I wrapped the whole thing in a `<div class="menu">` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I added the HTML code. But I'm still confused by your answer. I'm not having trouble getting it to show. It's the getting to be hidden first until the parent <li> is rolled over that I'm having trouble with. I added the site URL that I'm working on for an example too.

Comment: That can't be the entire code because there's no element `.menu`... but wrapping your code in a div still gives me the same results, while your old CSS made the level 3 menu visible when it shouldn't have. Did you even try this? I seriously don't get why this isn't exactly what you need, feel free to clarify.

Comment: Here's the first div (sorry)
<div id="navigation" class="menu">

I'll try it, I was just/am confused because I didn't think it should be showing either...

Comment: I WORKS?! So I added .menu ul li:hover ul, .menu ul a:hover ul, .menu ul ul li:hover ul { visibility:visible; } to the CSS but I'm not sure where to add the >

Comment: Well on your site, the third level only shows when I hover the first/second one because `.menu ul li:hover ul` selects all the `ul`s that are in the `li:hover` (first level). Using `>` makes it select only the ones that are *directly* inside the `li:hover`, which will work for an infinite number of submenus.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6451/discussion-between-madmartigan-and-talkingd0g)