# Need some help creating a third level menu on my navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have done a 2 level navigation and would wish to add a third level...despite reading up and trying to refer to some other css codes like  [CSS Drop Down Navigation, 3rd level issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752944/css-drop-down-navigation-3rd-level-issue) and http://forums.asp.net/t/1758667.aspx/1, i still couldn't get my code to work.

I am not sure if my current code would allow me to create a third level navigation. I am not a css wizard but would like to check if there is any way to create a third level.

I have added the contents for the third level but failed creating the CSS to make it appear. I tried adding:

```
   #menu li ul li ul { display:none;}
   #menu li ul li:hover > ul{display:block; position:absolute; left:150px;}
```

to me css but the third level did not appear

I wanted to check if the third level would even appear therefore, when i add

```
 #menu li ul ul { display:block;}
 #menu li ul li:hover > ul{display:block; position:absolute; left:150px;}
```

to my css the third level appeared but i know the result would be wierd.

The JSfiddle for my current code is : http://jsfiddle.net/eqNZd/5/

Thank you for helping me out...Sorry if my question confuses you...

P.S. I will be tidying my codes when i complete the navigation bar...sorry if the codes is untidy.

Comment: As a generic suggestion for your case - you could make your css easier by replacing deeply nested selectors with unique classes (mainly, easier to read and understand, but also better performance)

Comment: I'm just curious...why do you have all those nested `div`s? You can build the menu you want with just nested `<ul>`s

Comment: @jmeas i use to have a mega drop down navigation which have several properties which i need...and so i just copied and pasted the codes and change it to a normal dropdown instead of mega...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place to start. I looked at your code, but it seemed pretty convoluted, so I modified an old dropdown I wrote.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uW88/)

It's a very basic three-tier dropdown.

Here are some tips that have helped me write `CSS` dropdowns:

1. Keep the style and functionality separate
2. Keep it simple
3. Once you have one submenu done, you've done an infinite number of submenus. All you need to do is simply repeat *the same exact code* for every other submenu, making sure to select the correct `ul` in your `css`.

As you see, only 1 selector is needed for the header `ul` and 2 for each submenu `ul` for the menu to function. You should be able to modify this to do whatever it is that you need.

Comment: is it possible to use something like `<li class="stretch"></li>` with justify and inline-block properties to determine the space between each word in the navigation?

Comment: I don't think that doing that would conflict with anything in the code. Did you try it?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? I'll try and help!

Comment: hmm making the words on the navigation spread out evenly...by using the text align justify and adding a <li class stretch> into it

Comment: i am trying to make the words evely spread out throughout the width...so for example if i add another word in it would be evenly spread out accordingly...sorry if it confuses u...Thanks a  million...i will try on my end too...thanks